# Trouble with explosion animation

Tags: python, pygame

Here is my explosion class: I feel like I cycled through the list in an appropriate manner but the index never goes past 0 unless I originally set it to something different for `self.index`. In my game loop I have mouse detection set up and when I click the falling balloons the image changes only to the first explosion picture rather than cycling through all three in the list `self.red`

```py
class Explosion(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.red = [pygame.image.load('redImg1.png'),pygame.image.load('redImg2.png'),pygame.image.load('redImg3.png')]

        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.red[self.index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [x, y]
        self.counter = 0

    def update(self):
        self.counter += 1
        explosion_speed = 4
        #update explosion animation
        
        
        if self.counter >= explosion_speed and self.index < len(self.red) - 1:
            self.image = self.red[self.index]
            self.index += 1

        #if the animation is complete, reset animation index
            if self.index >= len(self.red) - 1 and self.counter >= explosion_speed:
                self.kill()
```

I made a sprite group for my explosion class and here is its implementation in the main game loop.

```
explosion_group=pygame.sprite.Group()
screen.blit(pygame.image.load("background.jpg"),(0,0))
def start():
    
    balloongroup.empty()
    allsprites.empty()
   
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                return
            if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                explosion = Explosion(pos[0], pos[1])
                
                allsprites.add(explosion)
                explosion_group.update()
```

Comment: is this any better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the sprite to the `explosion_group`. The explosion is animated in consecutive frames. Therefore `​explosion_group.update()` must be called in the application loop:

```py
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            explosion = Explosion(event.pos[0], event.pos[1])
            explosion_group.add(explosion)
            allsprites.add(explosion)
            
    explosion_group.update() 

    # [...]
```

---

`kill` is never called. The `update` needs to be redesigned:

```py
class Explosion(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def update(self):
        self.counter += 1
        explosion_speed = 4
        if self.counter >= explosion_speed:
            self.index += 1
            self.counter = 0

        if self.index < len(self.red):
            self.image = self.red[self.index]
        else:
            self.kill()
```

---

I suggest to limit the frames per second. Use [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) to control the frames per second and thus the game speed.

The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time. See [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick):

> This method should be called once per frame.

e.g.:

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    clock.tick(60)
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

class Explosion(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        #self.red = [pygame.image.load('redImg1.png'),pygame.image.load('redImg2.png'),pygame.image.load('redImg3.png')]
        self.red = img_list
        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.red[self.index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [x, y]
        self.counter = 0

    def update(self):
        self.counter += 1
        explosion_speed = 2
        if self.counter >= explosion_speed:
            self.index += 1
            self.counter = 0

        if self.index < len(self.red):
            self.image = self.red[self.index]
        else:
            self.kill()

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

img_list = []
for i in range(0, 250, 10):
    img_list.append(pygame.Surface((80, 80), pygame.SRCALPHA))
    pygame.draw.circle(img_list[-1], (255, 255-i, 0), (40, 40), round(1 + 39 * (250-i) / 250))
explosion_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            explosion = Explosion(event.pos[0], event.pos[1])
            explosion_group.add(explosion)
            #allsprites.add(explosion)
            
    explosion_group.update() 
            
    window.fill(0)
    explosion_group.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(100)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```